# Ask for new record on form load

Tags: vba, ms-access

When i load a form a want to ask my users if they want to make a new record otherwise i would like to load the last record, this because the form will fill in some data by default.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim Nieuw

Nieuw = MsgBox("New Record?", vbYesNo, "New Record?")

If Nieuw = 6 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Main", acNewRec
Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "Main", acLast
End If

End Sub
```

[When I use this script I got the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIzF3.png)

I couldn't find how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the defaults:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim Nieuw As VbMsgBoxResult

    Nieuw = MsgBox("New Record?", vbYesNo, "New Record?")

    If Nieuw = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Else
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thnx this solved indeed the problems. Sometime it is easy to solve things. I had only to change the  'DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast' to  'DoCmd.GoToRecord , "Main" , acLast'